# Как в Битрикс создать свойство инфоблока «До и после»?

Tags: битрикс

В инфоблоке надо реализовать поле, где можно указать начало и конец даты (таких дат несколько в одном элементе). Как это можно сделать на Битрикс? На картинке показано, как она должна примерно работать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тип поля `Строка`, в настройках данного свойства отметь `Множественное` и `Выводить поле для описания значения`

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то, что надо. А возможно создать подобное для свойства раздела?

Comment: если ответ помог, отметь пожалуйста, что верный. А в разделах там такого шика к сожалению нет

Answer (score 0):

Множественная строка не позволит решить данную задачу.

Если нужно вывести что то не стандартное, то можно использовать событие `OnIBlockPropertyBuildList` для добавления новых типов полей.

Например, в init.php:

```
$CEventManager = \Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance();
$CEventManager->addEventHandler("iblock", "OnIBlockPropertyBuildList", array('YouProp', "OnIBlockPropertyBuildList"), false, 10);
```

Класс `YouProp`:

```
class YouProp
{

    const PROP_CODE = 'YouProp';

    /**
    * @return array
    */
    function OnIBlockPropertyBuildList()
    {
        return array(
            "PROPERTY_TYPE"         => "S",
            "USER_TYPE"             => self::PROP_CODE,
            "DESCRIPTION"           => 'YouProp',
            "GetSettingsHTML"       => array("YouProp","GetSettingsHTML"),
            "PrepareSettings"       => array("YouProp","PrepareSettings"),
            "ConvertToDB"           => array("YouProp","ConvertToDB"),
            "GetPropertyFieldHtml"  => array("YouProp","GetPropertyFieldHtml"),
            "GetPublicEditHTML"     => array("YouProp","GetPublicEditHTML"),
            "GetPublicViewHTML"     => array("YouProp","GetPublicViewHTML"),
            );
    }

    /**
    * @param $arProperty
    * @param $value
    * @return mixed
    */
    function ConvertToDB($arProperty, $value)
    {
        # модификация перед сохранением
        $value["VALUE"] = ... ;

        return $value;
    }

    /**
    * @param $arProp
    * @param $value
    * @param $Control
    * @return string
    */
    function GetPublicViewHTML($arProp, $value, $Control)
    {

        return '';
    }

    /**
    * @param $arProp
    * @param $value
    * @param $Control
    * @return string
    */
    function GetPublicEditHTML($arProp, $value, $Control)
    {
        $html = '<input type="text" name="'.$Control["VALUE"].'" ...

        return  $html;
    }

    /**
    * @param $arProp
    * @param $value
    * @param $Control
    * @return string
    */
    function GetPropertyFieldHtml($arProp, $value, $Control)
    {
        $html = '<input type="text" name="'.$Control["VALUE"].'" ...

        return  $html;
    }

    /**
    * @param $arFields
    * @return mixed
    */

    function PrepareSettings($arFields)
    {
        # опции свойства    
        return $arFields["USER_TYPE_SETTINGS"];
    }

    /**
    * @param $arProp
    * @param $Control
    * @param $arPropertyFields
    * @return string
    */
    function GetSettingsHTML($arProp, $Control, &$arPropertyFields)
    {
        $arProp['USER_TYPE_SETTINGS'] = self::PrepareSettings($arProp);

        $prop = $arProp['USER_TYPE_SETTINGS'];

        # вывод html для настроек
    }
}
```

Еще [пример](https://gist.github.com/putalexey/f1bb84ca9f455e956308).